# Use result from previous query in another query in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

1st query:

```
    db.a.find({
    "type": ObjectId("50ed90f5a70defef23000002"),
    "config.name": "alpha"
 }, {
    "user": 1
 })
```

1st query result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5684035c91b4693b39547591"), "user" : ObjectId("54ba80ac2735eea200623612") }
```

2st query:

```
   db.users.find({
    "_id": ObjectId("54ba80ac2735eea200623612")
}, {
    "lastname": 1
})
```

can I combine these two queries into one query? 2st query uses 1st query result's `"user"` value `ObjectId("54ba80ac2735eea200623612")`

Comment: You could use the aggregate pipeline with `$lookup` but if this is a common operation It would be worth re-modeling your document for your given usage.

Comment: @KevinSmith sounds like you value electricity over data, although data multiplies much greater in variable exponentiality of expense.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an aggregation with a `$match` to match your condition and `$lookup` to map your local field `user` to your `user`collection `_id` field :

```
db.a.aggregate(
    [{
        $match: {
            "type": ObjectId("50ed90f5a70defef23000002"),
            "config.name": "alpha"
        }
    }, {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "user",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "users"
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: "$users"
    }]);
```

In Javascript, with `mongoose` for example you can do this with :

```
YourModel.aggregate(
    [{
        $match: {
            "type": ObjectId("50ed90f5a70defef23000002"),
            "config.name": "alpha"
        }
    }, {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "user",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "users"
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: "$users"
    }],
    function(err, result) {
        console.log("lastname : " + result.users.lastname);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [MongoDB doesn't support joins](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/), this can't be conbined into one query.

You can do this directly from the mongo shell very easily by firing first query, storing the result in a variable and then using it to fire second query.

```
var userDoc = db.a.findOne({"type" : ObjectId("50ed90f5a70defef23000002"),"config.name":"alpha" },{"user":1});
db.users.find({"_id" : userDoc.user},{"lastname":1})
```

If your first query returns multiple results, then

```
var cursor = db.a.find({"type" : ObjectId("50ed90f5a70defef23000002"),"config.name":"alpha" },{"user":1});
  cursor.forEach(function (userDoc) {
  var user = db.users.findOne({"_id" : userDoc.user},{"lastname":1});
  printjson(user);
})
```

Note: MongoDB supports [left outer join using $lookup in aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) since version 3.2

but in this case, that seems to be an overkill.

Comment: please see @Bertrand Martel answer

Comment: `userDoc.user` seems not work, "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue cannot compare to undefined"

Comment: @timy: actually `find()` returns a cursor and not the actual document, so if only one document is expected output, `findOne` would be more appropriate. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks